# Can a scala companion object have abstract members?

Tags: scala, implicit

EDIT: To make the problem more clear

I have a function that tries to parse a `Map[String, String]` into `ReadRequests` and `WriteRequests`. I need the `MapConvert` to be implicitly accessible from the abstract class `Request`.

```
// Conversion methods to make conversions from Map[String, String] to ReadRequest and WriteRequest implicit

trait MapConvert[A] {
    def convert(values: Map[String, String]): A
}

object Map2ClassHelpers {
    implicit class Map2Class(values: Map[String, String]) {
        def extract[A](implicit mapper: MapConvert[A]): A = mapper convert values
    }
}

// abstract Request class

abstract class Request[R <: Request[R]]() {
    def companion: RequestCompanion[R]
}

trait RequestCompanion[R <: Request[R]] {
    implicit val m: MapConvert[R]
}

// ReadRequest and companion object

case class ReadRequest(source: String, data: String)
    extends Request[ReadRequest] {
    override def companion: RequestCompanion[ReadRequest] = ReadRequest
}

object ReadRequest extends RequestCompanion[ReadRequest] {
    implicit val m = new MapConvert[ReadRequest] {
        def convert(values: Map[String, String]) = ReadRequest(
            source = values("source"),
            data = values("data")
        )
    }
}

// WriteRequest and companion object

case class WriteRequest(destination: String, data: String)
    extends Request[WriteRequest] {
    override def companion: RequestCompanion[WriteRequest] = WriteRequest
}

object WriteRequest extends RequestCompanion[WriteRequest] {
    implicit val m = new MapConvert[WriteRequest] {
        def convert(values: Map[String, String]) = WriteRequest(
            destination = values("destination"),
            data = values("data")
        )
    }
}

case class Spec(requestType: String, args: Map[String, String])

def fromMapToRequest[R <: Request[R]](spec: Spec)(implicit mR: Manifest[R]): R = {
    /* this extract method comes from Map2ClassHelpers
     * the result should be either a ReadRequest or a WriteRequest
     * the error happens at this call saying "could not find implicit value for parameter mapper
     * my guess is because it can't implicitly find the correct MapConvert from the abstract Request class
     */

    // a bunch of checks ...
    spec.args.extract[R]
}

def runExample() = {
    val spec1: Spec = Spec("read", Map("source" -> "/readPath", "data" -> "ABC"))
    val spec2: Spec = Spec("write", Map("destination" -> "/writePath", "data" -> "ABC"))

    val specs = Seq(spec1, spec2)

    specs.map(spec => {
        spec.requestType match {
            case "read" => fromMapToRequest[ReadRequest](spec)
            case "write" => fromMapToRequest[WriteRequest](spec)
        }
    })
}
```

This works when I change it to:

```
def fromMapToRequest[R <: Request[R]](spec: Spec)(eval: spec => Request)(implicit mR: Manifest[R]): R = {
    // a bunch of checks ...
    import Map2ClassHelpers._
    eval(spec)
}

def runExample() = {
    val spec1: Spec = Spec("read", Map("source" -> "/readPath", "data" -> "ABC"))
    val spec2: Spec = Spec("write", Map("destination" -> "/writePath", "data" -> "ABC"))

    val specs = Seq(spec1, spec2)
    import Map2ClassHelpers._
    specs.map(spec => {
        // this part is kind of ugly compared to the first way
        spec.requestType match {
            case "read" => fromMapToRequest[ReadRequest](spec)(_.args.extract[ReadRequest])
            case "write" => fromMapToRequest[WriteRequest](spec)(_.args.extract[WriteRequest])
        }
    })
}
```

but I'd like the more generalized first option so only have to specify the type in fromMapToRequest once.

Comment: Edited with a more fleshed out example demonstrating my problem.

Comment: Note that the first block of code scrolls down. When I looked at my own question, it looked like some code was missing, but it's really not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but if I do, the problem seems to be that you try to pass `implicit Manifest[R]` hoping that the compiler will be able to find the proper `MapConvert[R]` in the companion object and this approach doesn't work because `Manifest` does not extend the scope of the lookup for `implicit` parameters. But why can't you just pass `MapConvert[R]` itself as an `implicit` parameter into `fromMapToRequest`? When I change signature to

```
def fromMapToRequest[R <: Request[R]](spec: Spec)(implicit mc: MapConvert[R]): R = {
```

the code compiles and works as I would expect it to work (see it online [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/900nXo6nTLy91WYvTvJLZQ)). If you need `Manifest[R]` for your other checks, just pass two `implicit` parameters.

Comment: Wow, so simple and solved my complex problem. Thanks!

Comment: @user3685285, not everything in Scala has to be complicated :) Sometimes it is important to not over-engineer your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**(possibly outdated because of question edits)**

Define a trait for the companion objects:

```
trait FoobarCompanion[X <: Foobar[X]] {
  implicit val m: Converter[X]
}
```

Let the companion objects extend it:

```
object Foo extends FoobarCompanion[Foo] {
  implicit val m = Converter[Foo] { ... }
}

object Bar extends FoobarCompanion[Bar] {
  implicit val m = Converter[Bar] { ... }
}
```

Add a method `companion` to the `Foobar` itself:

```
abstract class Foobar[F <: Foobar[F]] {
  def companion: FoobarCompanion[F]
}
```

Now you have access to the correct implicit whenever you get an instance of `Foobar` through the `companion`.

You might want to take a look at how the code around [GenericCompanion](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/generic/GenericCompanion.html) is organized.

Comment: Thanks, I feel like this is going in the right direction, but  I don't understand how to implement `def companion: FoobarCompanion[F]` in the sub classes. Do those go in the class, or the companion object? My sub classes are case classes, so I can't really add methods to them.

Comment: @user3685285 Just return the companion object. `case class Foo(s: String) extends Foobar[Foo] { def companion: FoobarCompanion[Foo] = Foo }`

Comment: Hm, unfortunately, this isn't helping my methods find the `implicit val m = Converter[Foo]` when I run a  function that has this as an implicit parameter. Is there a way to do this where `Foobar` has implicit access to the `Converter` rather than having to call `companion` explicitly? I want it to work in the same way that `Foo` and `Bar` have access to `m` implicitly.

Comment: @user3685285 What do you mean by "helping [...] find". There is no "helping" or "not helping": the implicit definition is either in the implicit scope, or it is not. With the above definitions, every `Foobar[X]` obviously has access to a companion with an `implicit val m`. So, either you included this implicit into the implicit scope (then the compiler finds it), or you didn't (then the compiler doesn't find it, because it shouldn't). Please update your code with with the exact method invocation that doesn't work. (ah wait, didn't see your update yet, will read it in a minute)